# Rails 3 - uninitialized constant Setting::Paymentshop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, models, controllers

I am getting still this error, **Setting** and **Paymentshop** are models.

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :paymentshops
end


class PaymentShop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :setting
end
```

In view I have problem on this line:

```
dopr.paymentshops.type_v
```

**dopr** is variable with data from **Setting** and **type_v** is column in table **Paymentshops**.

I would like to ask you, If could anyone help me please with this error...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rails tries to automatically infer the model name from the relation name. With no indication of where to break the single lower-case stream of characters, it assumes that the target model is called `Paymentshops`.

You can explicitly override the expected class name with `has_many :paymentshops, :class_name => "PaymentShop"`. Alternatively, you could try using `has_many :payment_shops` - I'm not 100% sure how Rails modifies the relation names, but I think that should map to `PaymentShop` directly.

Comment: thank for your answer, `Chowlett`. I edited it on `has_many :payment_shop`, the original error is out, but now I am getting `undefined method `type_v' for #<Class:0x115309bc8>`, but I don't understand why, the column `type_v` exist in table `payment_shops`

Comment: Remember that `has_many` is stating that your class has, well, many of the mentioned type. So `dopr.payment_shops` is not a single PaymentShop on which you can call `type_v`, but an Array-like object of PaymentShops. (My apologies, I made a typo in my answer; should be `has_many :payment_shops`)